# Why do I need to write duplicate condition in this while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm working on the code returns the maximum number of consecutive 1's in the array. I used two while loops for this code.

```
public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    int maximum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < nums.length) {
        int conOnes = 0;
        while (i < nums.length && nums[i] == 1) {
            conOnes++;
            i++;
        }
        maximum = Math.max(maximum, conOnes);
        i++;
    }
    return maximum;
}
```

I already wrote `i < nums.length` in the first while loop condition, so I thought I don't need to write `i < nums.length` in the second while loop condition again. But when I omit `i < nums.length &&`  from the second one, it causes `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6`.
As the second while loop never be executed when i > nums.length,I don't get why I got this IOB exception.

Comment: Each loop uses it for a different reason. We do this check in the inner loop to prevent spill over at the end of the array, because the inner loop still advances through the array. And we need it in the outer loop for the sole reason of breaking out of the loop. You could also remove it from both loops and use a single check inside the inner loop `if(i >= nums.length-1){break;}`

Answer (score 0):

You might not need inner loop:

```
  public int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(int[] nums) {
    int maximum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int conOnes = 0;
    while (i < nums.length) {

      if (nums[i] == 1) {
        conOnes++;
      } else {
        conOnes = 0;
      }
      maximum = Math.max(maximum, conOnes);
      i++;
    }
    return maximum;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you maybe not realize is that the condition for a loop is only checked after completing a full iteration. It doesn't automatically jump out of the loop once the condition is met. So to demonstrate, consider this code:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < 5) {
    while (i < 10) {
        i++;
    }
}
System.out.println(i); //this will print 10
```

So it doesn't matter that the condition of the outer loop was met after an interation of the inner loop